# How to clear the attribute value of an element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, kendo-ui, selenium-webdriver, numeric-textbox

I have an element, which is kendo numeric textbox. It has values as well, I can get the value by using this code snippet `driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathlocator_value")).getAttribute("value");` but i want to clear the value and i want to update this element with another value. I tried
both the ways like using `clear()` and also`sendkeys(keys.control +"a",keys.delete)`
but its not working.

The html code is

```
    <form id="cashbookForm" class="form">
<div class="widget">
<table class="sTable taskWidget" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-bind="css:ExpenseID()==0?'non-printable':'',click:$root.CloseEditable">
<tr data-bind="css:ExpenseID()==0?'non-printable':''">
<td data-bind="text:Order">2</td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<div style="float: right;">
<span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox noform required" style="text-align: right;">
<span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-default">
<input class="k-formatted-value noform required k-input" type="text" style="text-align: right; display: inline;" tabindex="0" readonly="readonly">
<input class="noform required k-input" type="text" data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox: { value: Ca_TotalAmount, min: 0,format: '#.00'},uniqueName:true" style="text-align: right; display: none;" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" tabindex="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="251.44" name="ko_unique_4">
<span class="k-select">
</span>
</span>
</div>
</td>
<td> </td>
<td class="removeOnPrint">
</tr>
<tr class="removeOnPrint">
```

Here the numeric textbox present at

```
<input class="k-formatted-value noform required k-input" type="text" style="text-align: right; display: inline;" tabindex="0" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Any exceptions? Show us your code sample

Comment: We also will need to see the HTML produced by the numeric text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavascriptExecutor to achieve the goal.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("window.document.getElementById("elementID").setAttribute('value', ' ')");
```

or

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("window.document.getElementById("elementID").value = ' '");
```

If you want to use xPath:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.evaluate('xpath_locator', document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.value = ' '");
```

Comment: I tried you last code, still its not working, I tried like JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;   executor.executeScript("document.evaluate('.//tr[2]/td[6]/div/span/span/input[1]', document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.value = ' '");   table.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[2]/td[6]/div/span/span/input[1]")) .sendKeys("250.50"));   But it gives an error in the sendkeys, that it cant find that element is currently not visible and it can't interact with it. and also with your code it is not clearing the field.

Comment: Try `setAttribute('value', ' ')` instead of `value = ' '`. And also try to add timeouts, may be selenium works too fast and element is not loaded, when selenium tries to send keys.

Comment: As per your comment i changed the code like    executor.executeScript("document.evaluate('.//tr[2]/td[3]/span[@data-bind='text:GetName()']', document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.setAttribute('value', ' ')"); but now it gives an error like "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: missing ) after argument list
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6b', time: '2013-08-12 15:43:19'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_38'......."

Comment: Change `'.//tr[2]/td[3]/span[@data-bind='te‌​xt:GetName()']'` to `\".//tr[2]/td[3]/span[@data-bind='te‌​xt:GetName()']\"` and look for where ")" is missed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but I'm posting the answer here in case someone finds it useful. If you're using selenium and you want to remove attribute and not clear it, then here's what works:

```
public static void javascriptRemoveAttribute(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('required');", element);
}
```

It is similar to the first answer but they key is `removeAttribute`. ExecuteScript basically expects an array of elements. So you pass the element when needs to be modified and then remove its attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Using this function you can change the value of the element:

```
public void clearElementValueByJS(WebElement element, WebDriver driver, Stringvalue) {
    try {
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + value + "'", element);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

OR you can change the inner html value of the element:

```
public void setInnerHTMLValue(WebElement element, String value) {
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerText ='" + value + "'", element);
}
```